# Tumblr like and reblog button on same line

Tags: button, tumblr

This is what I've got:

```
{LikeButton size="15" color="white"} {ReblogButton size="15" color="white"}
```

Can anyone please help me make them be in the same line?

Comment: Put them in a table?  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478901/So-You-Want-To-Line-Up-Link-Buttons-Huh.htm

Comment: Need to see some more code, but I would wrap them in a container, and make sure float left is being used on the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a couple of ways:

```
.reblog_button, .like_button {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Or:

```
.reblog_button, .like_button {
    display: inline-block !important; /* important needed due to inline styling */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
<div id="buttons">{likebutton}</div>
<div id="buttons">{reblogbutton}</div>
```

And then in the CSS I put

```
#buttons {
float:right;
}
```